# Подскажите как сделать sql запрос в asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Хочу сделать в контролере запрос вида: `SELECT id, C_Name, COUNT(id) FROM command GROUP BY id`. Как реализовать в контролере и во вьюшке?

Попытки такие:

```
var commandsGrouped = db.Commands.GroupBy(s => s.id).Select(
    i => new { Word = i.Key, Count = i.Count() });
return View(commandsGrouped);
```

Но не знаю что написать во вью, где @model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new {}` в вашем коде создает анонимный класс. Так что единственное, что вы можете указать во View - это `dynamic`, при этом допечатка и остальные бонусы строгой типизации работать не будут.

Именно поэтому стоит объявить явный тип модели (добавив класс в папке Models):

```
public class MyKeyWithCount
{
    public int Word { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

использовать его вместо анонимного типа:

```
var commandsGrouped = db.Commands.GroupBy(s => s.id).Select(
        i => new MyKeyWithCount { Word = i.Key, Count = i.Count() }
    ).ToList();
return View(commandsGrouped);
```

и указать тип модели `@model List<MyKeyWithCount>`

`ToList()` стоит добавить ради того, чтобы все построение модели отработало в пределах действия контроллера, а не при рендеринге View.

Comment: Разобрался, большое спасибо!!